# Why is the statement "the bayes estimator is bayes optimal" profound?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, decision-theory, minimax

I'm trying to understand why people make a big deal about the optimality of a Bayes estimator. Certainly, if I have a Bayes estimator, then my expected loss is minimized, almost by definition. So,
$$
\text{Expected loss} = \mathbb E_{x,y}[L(\hat y_{\text{Bayes}}(x),y(x))] = \mathbb E_{x}[\mathbb E_{y(x)|x}[L(\hat y_{\text{Bayes}}(x),y(x))|x]] \leq  \mathbb E_{x}[\mathbb E_{y(x)|x}[L(\hat y(x),y(x))|x]]
$$
for any other $\hat y(x)$. But, by the same token, we could take the minimax loss and say
$$
\text{Expected minimax loss} =   \mathbb E_{x}[\max_{y(x)}[L(\hat y_{\text{minimax}}(x),y(x))|x]] \leq \mathbb E_{x}[\max_{y(x)}[\mathbb E_{y(x)|x}[L(\hat y(x),y(x))|x]
$$
for any other $\hat y(x)$? Is there some subtle notion of optimality that I am missing here? Or some reason why people care more about the "expected expected loss" rather than "expected other loss"?